# How to calculate mean pixels value of shapefile (for specific place)?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, pixel

I have GeoTIFF image. I want to know how to calculate specific area mean pixels values?
Is field calculator for(value*count fields) right or get raster properties? Or what can I do?

Comment: What software are you using? Please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ArcGIS the tool you are looking for is [Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/h-how-zonal-statistics-works.htm). You can mark out your your areas of interest with a shape file or feature class, and then use this as input along with your geotiff. I think QGIS has a similar zonal statistics tool if that's the software you are using.

Comment: Just to add to @ycartwhelen 's answer.  Here is a link to the Zonal Statistics plugin in QGIS.   https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html

Comment: @GBG QGIS 2 is no longer supported.  QGIS 3 link https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics